# Customize table header row for wordpress gutenberg table JUST for a single page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to be able to customize the table header row in my gutenberg table JUST for a single page.

I know I can do it by adding custom css under the "customize" section, but that changes the look of ALL tables that I will create for the site.

I also know that I can do it by simply adding custom html with the code editor view of the page, but if I do that wordpress will not allow the client to edit the table in the visual editor.

I want to add it to the stylesheet and then call it just for that particular table that I'm creating on that page, however when I add the code to the stylesheet and call it within the ***advanced>additional css*** section of the page it's not adding the properties.

(...yes ...the code below DOES work if I add it through ***"appearance>customize"***)

**CODE**

```
.blue-header thead {
    background-color: #030363;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

**CODE ADDED TO "ADDITIONAL CSS" SECTION**

```
 blue-header
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

It DOES works if I add the custom css in the "appearance>customize" section and then call to it on the page within the "advanced>additional css" section.

What was throwing me off was:

1. When I call to this custom code it wasn't showing the changes on the page within the visual editor, but it DID show on the live page once I hit update.
2. When I was adding the custom code in the appearance>customize section of the site it was showing the changes in real-time which made me think it was applying this to ALL tables within the site ...but I forgot I was already calling the custom code from the page within the "advanced>addition css" section.